# C# - Redirect from email body if the link doesn't load within 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I am sending email from my software which has two ip addresses.
One is real ip and the other one is internal.
When I send the email the url looks something like this:

https://***realipaddress***/Memo/MemoApproval?att=accept&queryString=%24HASH%24V1%2410000%246wqGezIN1QB6kxmuB47deLWZk4AlBAE8eESVoNx7Bw%2F1%2Bet2

OR,

https://***192.168.200.59***/Memo/MemoApproval?att=accept&queryString=%24HASH%24V1%2410000%246wqGezIN1QB6kxmuB47deLWZk4AlBAE8eESVoNx7Bw%2F1%2Bet2

I am doing this because my internal wifi doesn't allow the real ip address.
So, whenever some user uses the internal wifi the link becomes the later one.

I want these addresses to be interchanged if the request exceeds 10 seconds.

***The link is on email body***

Can that be possible? If so, then how do I do that?

Comment: Sounds impossible. Clicking the link involves a new request from the browser and you can't control that. Why don't just provide both links with a message that if the former doesn't work, users should try the latter.

Comment: @WiktorZychla it is actually a button as you can see there is an accept attribute so the user can't reallly see the link. They are given an option to click a butto. But I guess I nee two buttons now :(